# What was the ideological and philosophical underpinnings of World War II?

Tags: world-war-two

What was the ideological and philosophical underpinnings of World War II? How does imperialism fit into the causes of the war?

Comment: You can edit your previous question rather than start a new one using that "edit" link beneath the question.

Comment: Given my answer which could reasonably be interpreted to be snide I am reluctant to edit the tags to add "world-systems-theory", as such an edit could be viewed as unconstructive or a conflict of interests.

Answer (score 2):

WWII was an ideological conflict between different imperial power blocs within international capitalism, and in a few instances with colonised powers with local bourgeois who wished to be imperialist.  Chiefly, the capacity of existing blocs of capital to sustain themselves and their growth reached limits.

Comment: Questions at a certain level of abstraction get answers at a certain level of abstraction.

Comment: I thought this would be an answer for WWI rather than WWII.

Comment: That would depend on how seriously one takes one's Marxism, and, on the matter of "Imperialism" one's reading of Lenin; or, whether one is willing to throw a bedcover over the mess during inspections.

Comment: This is quite ridiculous. An argument can be made that the Second WW was in essence a continuation of the First; which was *inter alia* a war between empires. But of far greater relevance was that the Second World War was fought, on the Allied side, to deal with the pernicious Nazi and Fascist ideologies which had arisen in Europe out of German defeat and the peace treaty of 1918. Some historians have seen both wars as part of 'the course of German history' - notably A.J.P.Taylor in his book by that name. It is not a fashionable view.